# Put Outline When Focus on Input

Tags: css, reactjs, react-hooks

How do you put an outline on an input with border-radius? Pls check my codesandbox here
[CLICK HERE](https://codesandbox.io/s/verification-code-input-forked-zxell?file=/src/styles.css:689-705)

```
.code-inputs input:focus {
  outline: solid;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

Comment: you cannot:) you should try something else, like box-shadow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace outline with box-shadow

```
.code-inputs input:focus {
  outline: none;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 5px rgba(0, 123, 255, .5);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**For that, you'd use shadow:**

**Change:**

```
.code-inputs input:focus {
  outline: solid;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

**To**

```
.code-inputs input:focus {
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px rgba(0, 123, 255, .5);
}
```

---

**Example:**

```css
    input, input:focus {
        border: none;
        border-radius: 2pt;
        box-shadow: 0 0 0 1pt grey;
        outline: none;
        transition: .1s;
    }
    .text:focus {
        box-shadow: 0 0 0 2pt red;
    }
```

```html
    <input type=text class="text">
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `outline: solid;` use `box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px;`

Answer (score 0):

You can sort of cheat doing this by using `box-shadow` instead of the outline - I've had the same issues in the past when using rounded input boxes. Probably not the best solution out there, but definitely does the job.

```css
input {
  border-radius: 10px;
  height:30px;
  border: none;
  outline:none;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px #4f5b66;
}
input:focus {
  border-color:transparent;
  border:none;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px red;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" />
```

**[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5fcv0e7s/)**

Answer (score 0):

you cannot do that with outline, just like outline box-shadow does not cause the elements to change size, so you can apply an outline like border on focus.

```
.code-inputs input {
  outline: none;
}
.code-inputs input:focus {
   box-shadow: purple 0 0 5px;
}
```

I removed the extra stuff, but feel free to play with it.
Again the reason we use box-shadow is that when applied it will not change the size of the element so no reflow on the page.